# Z3PY converting Ints to Python int

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Is there a way to convert the Z3PY datatypes to native Python datatypes?

When my formula is solved by Z3, I can print it out by calling the model()-function. But how do I save the model output as ordinary ints in variables? So I can use them.

Can I convert them to ordinary ints so I can use them in the rest of my Python code in my program?

My whole purpose of using the solver is to take the result as an input to another Python program. So I need it to be able to process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your variable declared was `x`:

```
x = z3.Int("x")
```

You would get it as a Python int like this:

```
model[x].as_long()
```

z3 models are also iterable. Retrieving all parameters in a list comprehension:

```
[model[v] for v in model]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried retrieving all parameters in a list. Is it a way to also get the variable names? Now I got the values of the variables.

Comment: Well I didn't need that. The variables always have the same name so I can code them in myself. Thanks for the help, exactly what i needed! cheers

Comment: In case you need the variable names, the easiest way (though not really simple) is to look at the `model` dictionary itself. This can get rather complicated though. The best-known-method is to track your variables yourself, which should almost always be possible. (Unless you're writing utilities that should work for arbitrary programs.)